# Mostrar una fila de Google Sheets en mi HTML

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo una hoja de cálculo, un listado con Id, nombre, email.... y varias líneas.
He conseguido crear un html que me agrega un nuevo usuario en una nueva línea pulsando un botón.
Pero ahora estoy preparando un botón que haga una búsqueda desde un campo dado, es decir, que me devuelva los datos de id, nombre email... según una búsqueda (la búsqueda la hago desde el campo email.

El caso es que quiero que me devuelva los datos en el mismo html, (o uno nuevo) pero no lo consigo. He podido mostrar una variable `const`, gracias al formato html `<?= variable?>` en el html pero no actualiza tras la búsqueda. Alguien podría echarme una mano?

Dejo mi código:

```
function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('layout2');
  return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}   

function buscarPorEmail(emailParaBuscar){
      var  hojaListado = libro.getSheetByName("Listado user");
 
  var codigosDeTrabajadores = hojaListado.getRange("A2:T200");
  var datos = codigosDeTrabajadores.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < (hojaListado.getLastRow()-1); i++) {
     var filaDeInfo       = datos[i];
     var CodigoTrabajador = filaDeInfo[0];
     var Nombre           = filaDeInfo[1];
     var Email            = filaDeInfo[2];
     var Estado           = filaDeInfo[5];
            

if (emailParaBuscar == Email){

 var user_email     = hojaListado.getRange(NumeroFila,3).getValue();  hojaListado.getRange("s2").setValue(user_email);
 var user_estado    = hojaListado.getRange(NumeroFila,6).getValue();  hojaListado.getRange("s3").setValue(user_estado);
 var user_link      = hojaListado.getRange(NumeroFila,14).getValue(); 
var result = JSON.stringify(user_nombre);
  return result;

var mensaje = "Nombre: "+user_nombre;
}
 }
}
```

para el html:

```
<body>
            
      <input id="emailconsulta" type="text"   value=""  name="emailconsulta"    placeholder="Email del usuario"   onfocus="clearDiv()" />
      <input id="btnSend"     type="button"   onClick="buscarPorEmail()"   value="Consultar" />
      
    <!-- div donde se mostraran los resultados -->
    <div align="center" id="divResponse">
   </div>
    </body>
<script>
    
    function buscarPorEmail() {
      document.getElementById("divResponse").innerHTML = "Buscando...";
      var emailParaBuscar = document.getElementById("emailconsulta").value;
      google.script.run.buscarPorEmail(emailParaBuscar);
      alert("buscando "+ emailParaBuscar);
      
      var user = JSON.parse(user_nombre);
      document.getElementById("divResponse").innerHTML = user_nombre;
      enableInputs();
            
    }
```

Aquí sería donde se rellena el campo para buscar el email

```
<input id="emailconsulta" type="text"   value=""  name="emailconsulta"    placeholder="Email del usuario"   onfocus="clearDiv()" />
```

este el botón que arranca la función buscarPorEmail ()

```
<input id="btnSend"     type="button"   onClick="buscarPorEmail()"   value="Consultar" />
```

y la respuesta debería de aparecer, separada como en una tabla , id, nombre, email...
en el div

```
<div align="center" id="divResponse">
       </div>
```

Comment: Debes usar withSuccessHandler -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=withSuccessHandler

Comment: Hola Rubén, gracias por responder. Pero esto está dentro del "onclick" del botón, no? no hace falta añadir ningún <script> en que incluya esta función?

Comment: El Código de la pregunta no lo tiene.